# Vagrant change default webroot from /var/www to /var/www/app/web-suite/ shell script

Tags: shell, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I'm serving an index from `/var/www/app/web-suite/`, rather than `/var/www/` however I can't work out how to make it default to this location when I attempt to visit the box (i.e: `192.168.33.10`), my current provision script is as follows:

```
echo "running script in the VM"
apt-get updat
apt-get -y dist-upgrade
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Installing LAMP stack"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
apt-get install apache2
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password root | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password root | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y mysql-server
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get install -y php5
apt-get install -y php5-mysql
service apache2 restart
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Ruby Gems Installs"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
apt-get install -y ruby-full build-essential
gem install compass --version 0.12.6
gem install zurb-foundation
gem install rubygems-update
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Installing Composer"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/var/www/html
cd ../../var/www/html/
# wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
# chmod +x phpunit.phar
# mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
php composer.phar global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.0.*"
php composer.phar install
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Start up Compass Compiling"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
cd app/web-root/css/v1/
sudo compass init
sudo compass compile
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Provisioning Complete"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: How would you do it if you were doing it manually instead of with software?

Comment: Probably a virtual host @Quentin

Comment: And you would do that how? By creating a config file for the vhost it and putting that in a particular directory?

Comment: I'd likely place a `.conf` file in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory.

Comment: OK, so what's stopping you from doing that in your provision script?

Answer (score 1):

As is discussed in the comments to your question, I usually do this with a separate `.conf` which is then copied and enabled by the provision.

```
sudo cp /vagrant/<myconf>.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

And as a start for your custom `.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app/web-suite/
</VirtualHost>
```